# This is a c code to find the average in an array of 50 elements using a function

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float Findaverage(float n,float numbers[]) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        sum += numbers[j];
    }
    printf("The average number of the array is: %f", sum/n);

}




int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    float numbers[50];
    float average;
    printf("Enter 50 elements: ");
    // taking input and storing it in an array
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        scanf("%f", &numbers[i]);
    }
    average = Findaverage(50,numbers[50]);
    printf("\nThe average number of the array is: %f", average );

    return 0;
}
```

The output gives an error "passing 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'float *'; take the address with &". Why is this?

Comment: Your code is broken. The error is indicating that the argument expected shall be a pointer, while you pass a float value. You should change the 2nd argument to the call of findAverage to a pointer, probably you want to pass the pointer to the first element of numbers - so simply use numbers. Btw, you pass the 50th element, which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the function `Findaverage` returns nothing.

You need to add this statement to the function

```
return sum / n;
```

And the first parameter shall have an integer type instead of the type `float`.

```
float Findaverage(float n,float numbers[]) {
                  ^^^^^
```

Secondly in this call of the function

```
average = Findaverage(50,numbers[50]);
```

the argument `numbers[50]` having the type `float` instead of the type `float *` is invalid. You need to write

```
average = Findaverage(50,numbers);
```

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
double Findaverage( const float numbers[], size_t n ) 
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    return n == 0 ? 0.0 : sum / n;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
double average = Findaverage( numbers, sizeof( numbers ) / sizeof( *numbers ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
average = Findaverage(50,numbers[50]);
```

to

```
average = Findaverage(50,numbers);
```

`numbers[50]` refers to a single array element, not the entire array.  It's also one past the end of your array (which is indexed from `0` to `49`).